# Too many levels of symlinks?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I am attempting to re-install `pip` using `easy_install`.

When I run `easy_install pip`, I get the following error message:

```
easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.4.1
Adding pip 1.4.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/pip: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

How can I remove the symlink?  Alternatively/related - is `pip` installed already?

Comment: what does `ls -Fal /usr/local/bin/pip` give you?

Comment: @MattDMo `lrwxr-xr-x  1 mike  admin  3 Dec 23 22:18 /usr/local/bin/pip@ -> pip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, `/usr/local/bin/pip` is a symlink pointing to itself, and `easy_install` is getting confused trying to write to it, instead of just deleting it first. You can do that yourself by running

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip
```

then rerunning the installation process.

Comment: I was having the same problem, except in a virtualenv. My `~/.virtualenvs/envname/bin/pip` was somehow set to a symlink to itself. I removed the symlink but pip couldn't repair itself so I had to create a new virtualenv from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This may have nothing to do with python. Infinite recursion may be the cause.  You can create a symbolic link to a non-existent file under Linux (Linux MYMachine 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Here norealfile.fa is a link to self.

```
norealfile.fa -> /some/real/dir/norealfile.fa
```

Under linux, if you do

```
ls /some/real/dir/norealfile.fa
```

You should get an error message:

```
ls: cannot access /some/real/dir/norealfile.fa: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

In Mac OS, you will get "ls: /some/real/dir/norealfile.fa No such file or directory"

Let me know if you get something else on your OS.  The implementation detail of symbolic link in different OS may dictate the exact behavior of self referencing symbolic links.